# Mongo DB show all collections except one

Tags: javascript, mysql, mongodb, nosql, robo3t

in Mongo DB how can I retrieve all documents except one which is Test

my code shows all the documents

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection) { 
    var result = db[collection]; 
    if(result != 'Test') { 
        print("All the documents: " + " for collection: "+ collection);
    } 
});
```

Comment: seems like you are checking if a collection is not equal to test instead of checking the document. Do you want to check if the collection isn't test or if a document isn't test? These are two different things.

Comment: Hello Daniel I have a colleciton name test and I do not want to list this collection

Comment: `db.getCollectionNames()` returns an array of collection names (each name as a string). So, why do you need the `var result = db[collection];`?

Comment: Yeah, should just be "if (collection != 'Test')".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct is:

```
  db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection){
     if(collection != 'Test') {
         print("All the documents: " + " for collection: "+ collection);
        }
       }
      );
```